# Xamarin.Forms font family not working for UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, fonts, uwp, xamarin.forms

I have been following the Xamarin guide to adding fonts to my app.  I have not had any issues with iOS or Android, but my UWP app is ignoring the font and using the default font.

I added my font to my UWP project in Assets\Fonts\FiraSans-Regular.otf.

[image: uwp]

My XAML markup to apply the font is as follows:

```
<Label HeightRequest="50" Text="My sample text">
  <Label.FontFamily>
    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
      <OnPlatform.iOS>FiraSans-Regular</OnPlatform.iOS>
      <OnPlatform.Android>FiraSans-Regular.otf#FiraSans-Regular</OnPlatform.Android>
      <OnPlatform.WinPhone>Assets/Fonts/FiraSans-Regular.otf#FiraSans</OnPlatform.WinPhone>
    </OnPlatform>
  </Label.FontFamily>
</Label>
```

Does this appear to be the correct way to apply a font for my UWP app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've downloaded the Font and you did almost correct. Add the space in font name:

```
<OnPlatform.WinPhone>Assets/Fonts/FiraSans-Regular.otf#Fira Sans</OnPlatform.WinPhone>
```

You have to use correct font name which you can find during font installation.

Comment: Thank you so much! Saved me so much time tracking down why my font wasn't loading on UWP.

Comment: You saved me to write a custom class, thanks (`GloriaHallelujah.ttf` - `Gloria Hallelujah`)